# Получение BreadCrumb (Хлебные крошки) в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Может кто сталкивался, существует таблица:

```
|id|owner|
|1 |0|
|2|0|
|3|1|
|4|2|
|5|3|
```

т.е. обычное дерево, где id уникальный идентификатор, owner - id владелеца, к примеру, задан id=5, необходимо запросом получить строку: 1/3/5 т.е. полный путь от запрашиваемого элемента до самого старшего родителя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В модели adjacency list — у вас именно такая — невозможно получить полный путь (произвольной глубины) одним SQL запросом.

Путь до заданной глубины можно получить саморефернсным запросом, например:

```
SELECT
    child1.id as level1,
    child2.id as level2,
    child3.id as level3
FROM adlist parent
    LEFT JOIN adlist AS child1 ON child1.id=parent.id
    LEFT JOIN adlist AS child2 ON child2.id=child1.owner
    LEFT JOIN adlist AS child3 ON child3.id=child2.owner
```

Comment: А если дерево из четырех уровней? Пяти? Шести?... Не вижу в мускуле универсального решения.

Comment: При чем тут именно MySQL? Я ведь ясно сказал: в модели AL невозможно одним запросом выбрать путь произвольной глубины.

Часто нужен полный путь — пожалуйста, есть Materialized Path, который по определению хранит для каждого узла полный путь в таблице.

Comment: Значить остаются только процедуры.

Comment: Или Materialized Path

Comment: Структуру базы незя менять, таковы уж условия. )

Comment: Хранимые процедуры тоже нельзя?

Comment: Можно ) я же говорю, на них вся надежа и осталась )

Comment: Ну тогда успехов! обойти AL и составить путь несложно будет

Answer (score 1):

Я всегда делал так, да простят меня программеры:

```
function getParent($id){
$path = array[$id];
$sql = 'select `owner` from `tree` where `id`='.$id;
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0 && $row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
if($row->owner!=0){
$arr = getParent($id);
$path = array_merge($path,$arr);
}
}
return $path;
}
```

Как-то так.

Comment: да, но необходимо именно запросом ) без php

Answer (score 1):

Да ну? Серьезно что ли, нельзя получить полный путь?

Вот пример из MS SQL

```
with t (id, parent, path)
as (
select id, PARENT, CAST (ID AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE ID = 5
UNION ALL
SELECT T2.ID, T2.PARENT, CAST(T2.ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '/' + T.[PATH]
FROM TABLE1 T2
INNER JOIN t ON T.PARENT = T2.ID)
SELECT path FROM T WHERE parent = 0
```

Только вот в MySQL такого сделать нельзя - не работают в нем рекурсивные запросы. Если очень надо запросом - ищите по ключевому слову nested sets.

Comment: T-SQL — это уже процедурщина. Тогда можно вспомнить, что в MySQL тоже есть CREATE FUNCTION, например. А обычным декларативным селектом получить полный путь нельзя. В nested sets, кажется, тоже нельзя, не помню точно.

Comment: кто говорил про один декларативный селект? Вопрос был - как получить путь средствами SQL. Запрос один? Один.

Comment: Если мы принимаем во внимание всякие расширения к ANSI SQL, то я тогда напишу UDF-функцию и скажу, что можно решить задачу так:
SELECT full_path_in_tree(id) WHERE id = 1

И тоже скажу, что запрос один :)

Comment: пожалуй неверно поставил метку sql, да задача должна быть выполнена для mysql

Answer (score 0):

Не панацея, но какое-никакое доказательство того, что "решение" возможно...
Если выполняются два условия, то можно получить путь одним запросом.
Условия:

1. Максимальная глубина пути невелика и заранее известна.
2. Индекс корня (начального узла) известен. (или, например, самый старший родитель имеет родителя 0)

запрос (при максимальной глубине 3):

```
SELECT    t1.id as level1,
t2.id as level2,
t3.id as level3
FROM adlist AS t1
LEFT JOIN adlist AS t2 ON t2.owner = t1.id
LEFT JOIN adlist AS t3 ON t3.owner = t2.id
WHERE t1.owner = 0 AND ((t1.id = ID AND t2.id IS NULL) OR (t2.id = ID AND t3.id IS NULL) OR (t3.id = ID));
```

где ID - искомый элемент...

Можно, конечно, написать запрос, который сможет обработать много уровней... Но... если таблица большая, боюсь сервер БД не вынесет такого издевательства...